# SPServices CAML Query Not Working

Tags: javascript, caml-query, spservices, caml

I have the following CAML filter:

```
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>WD</Value></Contains></Where></Query>",
```

This returns everything that has WD in the Title. However when I add an AND:

```
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><AND><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>WD</Value></Contains><Contains><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Choice'>Active</Value></Contains></AND></Where></Query>",
```

Returns nothing. I know there are titles that contain WD and are Active.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest  using the CAMLQuery only with  your status columns for make sure if this is returning something.

Second, you might use the `<Eq>` tag instad of `<Contains>` tag

And finally, when you are sure you have data when querying the status column. Put togheter the Title and the Status queries with the `<And>` tag